# Display canvas shape always on top of another shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have two moving rectangles in my canvas, one is green and one is red. When they are on the same position and you can see only one of them, the red rectangle is always displayed while the green one simply is under the red one.

How can i accomplish that the green one is always displayed on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without any code it is hard to tell, but if you have the code for the green rectangle first it will be drawn first and the red will be drawn on top of it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should paint the green one AFTER the red one. so if your rectangles are in an array, you can iterate on it in reverse order

```js
(function start() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth || $(window).width();
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight || $(window).height();
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const draw = function(opts={color: 'yellow', x: 0, y: 0}) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(opts.x, opts.y, 150, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = opts.color;
    ctx.fill();
  }

  // COLUMN 1
  draw({color: 'red',x: 20,y: 20});
  draw({color: 'green',x: 40,y: 40});
  
  // COLUMN 2
  draw({color: 'green', x: 200, y: 20});
  draw({color: 'red', x: 220, y: 40});
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```